# Alfresco: How to use ScriptNode processTemplate API without a document?

Tags: alfresco

I'd like to use the Freemarker templating engine from within a controller's webscript to process some expression.

I've seen Alfresco provide the `document.processTemplate("template content here")` API.

The documentation says: "Executes a template from the repository against the current Document node"

Let's say I don't have any specific document to use, I just want to execute the templating engine and retrieve the output. What's the best way to do it?

Should I use some sort of temporary or "proxy" document? What's the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite understandning what you are after here, I however think this is possible (not sure why anyone would like to do it though.)

You write your own class extending the BaseTemplateProcessorExtension, in that class you could write a method performing the stuff you want.

```
public class MyTemplateProcessorExtension extends BaseTemplateProcessorExtension {

  public String myMethod(){
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

Declare it the following way in your spring config.

```
<bean id="templateHelper" parent="baseTemplateImplementation" class="my.alfresco.repo.template.TemplateHelper">
  <property name="extensionName" value="templateHelper" />
 </bean>
```

Then you can call it from your freemarker with:

`${templateHelper.myMethod()}`

The freemarker template calling "myMethod" should be a node in the repository  (it should be possible to place it in the classpath as well, however I never had any success with this), since the processTemplate needs a nodeRef to the template itself.

Ok, please beware. I don't recommend this approach for anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to not use a document. So use a folder like data dictionary or create a dummy document with no content you always use.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of alfresco is managing document.What kind of output you will produce without having value of any metadata of document in the template.This is the main reason behind this is not supported in alfresco, template engine is designed in such a way so that we can process any document.